# Paste the elements of two columns

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, paste, rcpp

I have a data.frame of the following kind

```
set.seed(12)
d = data.frame(a=sample(5,x=1:9), 
               b=sample(5,x=1:9),
               c=sample(5,x=1:9),
               d=sample(5,x=1:9),
               e=sample(5,x=1:9),
               f=sample(5,x=1:9))

d
#   a b c d e f
# 1 1 1 4 4 2 3
# 2 7 2 7 9 7 5
# 3 8 5 3 8 1 2
# 4 2 9 8 7 5 9
# 5 9 6 2 1 9 4
```

I would like to take the first two columns, convert the integer into characters and paste the two elements of the same row together. Then repeat the process each successive pair of columns.

Here is a script that would do the job correctly:

```
bar = function (twocols) {sapply(1:nrow(twocols), FUN=function(x) {paste(twocols[x,], collapse="")} )}

    count = 0
    out = matrix(0, ncol=ncol(d)/2, nrow=nrow(d))
    for (i in seq(1,ncol(d), 2)) {
       count = count+1
       out[,count] = bar(d[,i:(i+1)])
    }

print(out)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "11" "44" "23"
[2,] "72" "79" "75"
[3,] "85" "38" "12"
[4,] "29" "87" "59"
[5,] "96" "21" "94"
```

But my data.frame is actually very big and looping through the whole data.frame in R is very slow. Do you have a more efficient solution? `Rcpp` might be the solution but I don't know how to code in C++.

Comment: It seems the output you give does not correspond to the data you provide. This might cause some confusion, so maybe correct the output of `print(out)`

Comment: From your description, it doesn't sound like you want a `collapse` argument to `paste`.

Comment: `sapply(seq(1, ncol(d), 2), function(x) paste0(d[, x], d[, x+1]))`
Though it uses the global variable inside the function ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This matches your description, but not the output you show:

```
mat = as.matrix(d)

matrix(paste0(mat[, seq(1, ncol(mat), by = 2)],
              mat[, seq(2, ncol(mat), by = 2)]),
       ncol = ncol(mat) / 2)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "11" "44" "23"
# [2,] "72" "79" "75"
# [3,] "85" "38" "12"
# [4,] "29" "87" "59"
# [5,] "96" "21" "94"
```

You could, of course, convert the result to numeric, back to a data.frame, etc.

Comment: Awesome. Sorry for my output, I changed the seed somehow. Your output is the right one. That seems to be about the most efficient solution one could find with R +1

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
m <- as.matrix(10*d[c(T,F)]+d[c(F,T)])
m[] <- as.character(m)
```

Comment: Good idea if they're all single digits.

Comment: @Frank Thank you. I think it's pretty fast too. I'm having trouble getting the benchmark together for all answers.