# Combine two dataframe columns in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe such as:
A  B  C
a  a  a
a  b  b
d  e  a

and I want to create a new column in the dataframe that is B and C combined (call it D).

A  B  C  D
a  a  a  aa
a  b  b  bb
d  e  a  ea

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30927899/1191259

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste`.

```
  df1$D <- do.call(paste0, df1[c('B', 'C')])
```

Or

```
  df1 <- transform(df1, D= paste0(B,C))
```